# Tetris Rotation Algorithm not working

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I'm working with a Tetris rotation algorithm. I used the algorithm in my another winforms app a while ago and it worked just fine. Now I want to write a tetris game in Android so I write the algorithm in Java again.

However, this time it doesn't work. I wrote the algorithm quite a while ago when I was a beginner programmer so the code is kind of bad. Here is the algorithm in Java:

```
public static final int CLOCKWISE = 1;
public static final int ANTICLOCKWISE = -1;

public static Point rotateClockwise (int x, int y) {
    int temp;
    temp = y;
    y = x;
    x = -temp;
    return new Point (x, y);
}

public static Point rotateAnticlockwise (int x, int y) {
    int temp;
    temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = -temp;
    return new Point (x, y);
}

public static boolean tryRotateTetrimino (Tetrimino tetrimino,
        int rotationPointBlockIndex, int direction) {

    //Local variable declarations
    boolean a, b, c, d;
    TetrisBlock rotationBlock = tetrimino.blocks[rotationPointBlockIndex];
    int X1, Y1, X2, Y2, X3, Y3, X4, Y4;

    //Assign coordinates relative to the centre of rotation.
    X1 = tetrimino.blocks[0].getX () - rotationBlock.getX ();
    Y1 = tetrimino.blocks[0].getY () - rotationBlock.getY ();
    X2 = tetrimino.blocks[1].getX () - rotationBlock.getX ();
    Y2 = tetrimino.blocks[1].getY () - rotationBlock.getY ();
    X3 = tetrimino.blocks[2].getX () - rotationBlock.getX ();
    Y3 = tetrimino.blocks[2].getY () - rotationBlock.getY ();
    X4 = tetrimino.blocks[3].getX () - rotationBlock.getX ();
    Y4 = tetrimino.blocks[3].getY () - rotationBlock.getY ();

    //Rotate the coordinates.
    if (direction == CLOCKWISE) {
        X1 = rotateClockwise (X1, Y1).x;
        Y1 = rotateClockwise (X1, Y1).y;
        X2 = rotateClockwise (X2, Y2).x;
        Y2 = rotateClockwise (X2, Y2).y;
        X3 = rotateClockwise (X3, Y3).x;
        Y3 = rotateClockwise (X3, Y3).y;
        X4 = rotateClockwise (X4, Y4).x;
        Y4 = rotateClockwise (X4, Y4).y;
    } else {
        X1 = rotateAnticlockwise (X1, Y1).x;
        Y1 = rotateAnticlockwise (X1, Y1).y;
        X2 = rotateAnticlockwise (X2, Y2).x;
        Y2 = rotateAnticlockwise (X2, Y2).y;
        X3 = rotateAnticlockwise (X3, Y3).x;
        Y3 = rotateAnticlockwise (X3, Y3).y;
        X4 = rotateAnticlockwise (X4, Y4).x;
        Y4 = rotateAnticlockwise (X4, Y4).y;
    }

    //Declares two arrays of absolute x and y coordinates.
    int[] xArray = new int[] { rotationBlock.getX() + X1,
            rotationBlock.getX() + X2,
            rotationBlock.getX() + X3,
            rotationBlock.getX() + X4 };
    int[] yArray = new int[] { rotationBlock.getY() + Y1,
            rotationBlock.getY() + Y2,
            rotationBlock.getY() + Y3,
            rotationBlock.getY() + Y4 };

    //Check if the coordinates are valid
    a = tetrimino.checkPositionValid (xArray[0], yArray[0]);
    b = tetrimino.checkPositionValid (xArray[1], yArray[1]);
    c = tetrimino.checkPositionValid (xArray[2], yArray[2]);
    d = tetrimino.checkPositionValid (xArray[3], yArray[3]);

    //If the coordinates are valid, assign them to each of the blocks.
    if (a && b && c && d) {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++) {
            tetrimino.blocks[i].setX (xArray[i]);
            tetrimino.blocks[i].setY (yArray[i]);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

I think this code is really hard to understand for everyone except me. I used to write the worst code in the world. This method returns true when the terimino can rotate and is rotated. The parameter rotationPointBlockIndex indicates the center of rotation. Therefore, I can try to rotate the tetrimino about every tetris block, like this:

```
if (TetrisUtility.tryRotateTetrimino (this, 0, TetrisUtility.CLOCKWISE))
        TetrisUtility.addRotationIndex (this);
    else if (TetrisUtility.tryRotateTetrimino (this, 1, TetrisUtility.CLOCKWISE))
        TetrisUtility.addRotationIndex (this);
    else if (TetrisUtility.tryRotateTetrimino (this, 2, TetrisUtility.CLOCKWISE))
        TetrisUtility.addRotationIndex (this);
    else if (TetrisUtility.tryRotateTetrimino (this, 3, TetrisUtility.CLOCKWISE))
        TetrisUtility.addRotationIndex (this);
```

Please note that the setX and setY methods will change the physical position of the tetris block.

I do exactly the same thing as before but it just doesn't work.
For example:

```
O
O
O O
```

rotate, and turns into

```
O
  O
    O
```

It seems like two of the tetris blocks have overlapped.

If you think my algorithm is wrong and want to suggest another one, can you explain it in terms of the Tetrimino class and the TetrisBlock class?

Tetrimino.java

```
public abstract class Tetrimino {
public TetrisBlock[] blocks;

protected int interval = 1000;
protected boolean paused = false;
protected Handler handler;
protected TetrisBlock[][] tetrisBlockMatrix;
protected ArrayList<ITetrisEventListener> landedEventListeners;
protected Runnable task = new TimerTask () {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (!paused) {
            moveDown ();
            if (handler != null)
                handler.postDelayed (task, interval);
        }
    }
};

public static final int LEFT = -1;
public static final int RIGHT = 1;

protected abstract TetrisBlock[] getTouchingSides();

protected void landed () {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < landedEventListeners.size () ; i++) {
        landedEventListeners.get (i).onLanded (this);
    }
}

public void registerLandedListeners (ITetrisEventListener listener) {
    landedEventListeners.add (listener);
}

public void moveDown () {
    if (!checkLanded ()) {
        for (TetrisBlock block:blocks) {
            block.moveDown ();
        }
    } else {
        handler = null;
        landed ();
    }
}

protected boolean checkLanded () {
    TetrisBlock[] touchingSides = getTouchingSides ();
    for (TetrisBlock block:touchingSides) {
        if (block.getY () >= 21) {
            return true;
        }

        if (tetrisBlockMatrix[block.getX ()][block.getY () + 1] != null) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean checkPositionValid (int x, int y) {
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 ||
            x > 15 || y > 21)
        return false;
    if (tetrisBlockMatrix[x][y] == null)
        return true;
    return false;
}

public void move (int side) {
    if (side == 1 || side == -1) {
        for (TetrisBlock block:blocks) {
            block.setX (block.getX () + side);
        }

        for (TetrisBlock block:blocks) {
            if (!checkPositionValid (block.getX (), block.getY ())) {
                if (side == LEFT)
                    move (RIGHT);
                else
                    move (LEFT);
            }
        }
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ();
    }
}

public void addTetrisBlocksToMatrix (TetrisBlock[][] matrix) {
    for (TetrisBlock block:blocks) {
        if (matrix[block.getX ()][block.getY ()] == null) {
            matrix[block.getX ()][block.getY ()] = block;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ();
        }
    }
}

public void setTimerEnabled (boolean value) {
    if (value && paused) {
        handler.post (task);
    } else {
        paused = true;
    }
}

public void setTimerInterval (int milliseconds) {
    interval = milliseconds;
}

protected Tetrimino (TetrisBlock[][] matrix, TetrisActivity activity) {
    this.tetrisBlockMatrix = matrix;
    handler = new Handler ();
    handler.post (task);
    landedEventListeners = new ArrayList<> ();
    blocks = new TetrisBlock[4];
}
```

}

TetrisBlock.java

```
public class TetrisBlock {
private static final int LENGTH_IN_DP = 20;
private TetrisActivity activity;
private ImageView picture;
private int color;
private int x;
private int y;

private AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams getLayoutParams () {
    return (AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams) picture.getLayoutParams ();
}

public TetrisActivity getActivity() {
    return activity;
}

public ImageView getPicture() {
    return picture;
}

public int getY() {
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams ();
    return params.y / getLengthInPixels ();
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams ();
    params.y = y * getLengthInPixels ();
    picture.setLayoutParams (params);
}

public int getX() {
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams ();
    return params.x / getLengthInPixels ();
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams ();
    params.x = x * getLengthInPixels ();
    picture.setLayoutParams (params);
}

public int getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setColor(int color) {
    this.color = color;
    picture.setBackgroundColor (color);
}

public TetrisBlock (int color, int x, int y, TetrisActivity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
    picture = new ImageView (activity);
    setColor (color);
    picture.setImageResource (R.drawable.tetrisblock);

    int w, h;
    w = getLengthInPixels ();
    h = getLengthInPixels ();
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams params = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams (w,
            h, x * getLengthInPixels (), y * getLengthInPixels ());

    picture.setLayoutParams (params);
    picture.setScaleType (ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

    ((AbsoluteLayout)activity.findViewById (R.id.main_frame)).addView (picture);
}

public void moveDown () {
    setY (getY () + 1);
}

public int getLengthInPixels () {
    return (int)(LENGTH_IN_DP * activity.getScale () + 0.5F);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you rotate, you are setting the X co-ordinate to the new value and overwriting the old one, when you still need it for the second call to the rotation function. For example the rotated value of X1 is passed to the second call of `rotateClockwise` here, when you should be passing the original value:

```
X1 = rotateClockwise (X1, Y1).x;
Y1 = rotateClockwise (X1, Y1).y;
```

Just call it once and then assign the x and y values to the variables:

```
Point point1 = rotateClockwise (X1, Y1);
X1 = point1.x; Y1 = point1.y;
```

Comment: Oh yes, I see! Thank you very much! I try that.